# phpmyadmin dosen't work in Windows Server, extension mysqli is missing

Tags: php, windows, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with phpmyadmin. Throws me an error message that says the following. `"The mysli extension is missing. Please chech you PHP configration ...."` I do not understand why I get the error message because I in my php.ini uncomment the extension called `"extension = mbstring"` and `"extension = mysqli "`. I have tried differently and still I get the same error I don't know if I have to change something in the Apache configuration file to make it work.

Here the error message: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the following config for extensions in php.ini file

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
;extension=php_gd2.dll
```

Comment: After making changes you need to restart your apache server did you do so?

Comment: I did, but I fix the problem

Comment: The error was in the Apache httpd.conf file. I put the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still have the error, and it isn't dissapearing (it happened to me after trying everything).

I did the following:

**1.** Check that the "extension_dir" in "php.ini" is refering to the extension dir
"*/xamp/php/ext"

**2.** In the same file "php.ini" search for "extension=exif" (the one that says "Must be after mbstring as it depends on it") and under it place -> "extension=php_mysqli.dll"
After that, check that you don't have any "php_mysqli.dll" duplicated in all those extensions, if so, just comment it placing ";" in front of it.

**3.** After that, go to "*\xamp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php" and where it says:

/* Authentication type and info */ put the same login you used when creating the localhost user -> (usually) "['user'] = 'root';"  ['password'] = 'thePasswordYouUsed';

// I don't know if this  is necessary but I just deleted the "mnb" or something like that
that was appearing in "/* User for advanced features */" "['controluser']" = '';
now I have it like that -> "['controluser']" = '';"

**4.** After that, open your xamp control panel, stop apache service, wait, and start it again.

**5.** Then open a new navigator tab and go to your "localhost/phpmyadmin", in my case it is -> "http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/" (I previously changed the port from 80 to 8080 in the configuration files, because the port 80 was already being used)

---

---

Hope it worked for you. I'm not a pro in this things but I just persisted in trying to solve my problem, searching and searching until I found the way for me to work.
When I finnaly solved it, I wanted to share my experience, because I appreciate a lot when people do this and I can get benefit from it. So I decided to take a moment and give back to the community! ^^